# &::before Pseudo element not aligning properly - CSS(3) Box Model - LESS

Tags: css, layout, alignment, less, pseudo-element

I'm trying to add an image with the `&::before` pseudo element and place it on top of it's parent element by adjusting the padding/margin. I have not be able to place the img "on top" of it's parent element. It resides within the box of the parent. I have tried setting both elements to `display:block`. I have attempted to use relative/absolute positioning. I have adjusted margins/padding without a solution.

HTML:

```
<div class="foo">
   <div class="title">title</div>
   <div class="body">text</div>
</div>
```

LESS/CSS:

```
.foo {
  display:block;
  padding: 1em;

  &:before {
    background-image: url("bar.svg");
    padding: .25in;  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    background-position: top outside;
    background-color: white;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    max-width: (@column + .45in);    
    margin-left: -.15in;
    margin-top:-.5in;
  }
}
```

I would expect adjusting the value of the margins on the pseudo element would produce the expected result. However this is not the case. Is there a limitation I'm unaware of?

Thanks for your time and your help.

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle for the same? That would be helpful for developers to understand the actual issue.

Answer (score 1):

First, I assume by "on top" you mean displayed "before" the `.foo` element. I assume that based on what it appears you are trying to do with your code. Normally, I would interpret "on top" as a higher `z-index` and overlapping an element, but I don't think that is what you are asking.

Second, unless I am unfamiliar with something (definitely possible), there is no `outside` keyword for `background-position`; therefore, that would seem to be an error (though I would not expect it to cause the issue you face).

Third, *I would think that your basic premise should be working*. [This fiddle demonstrates a shifting of the `:before` element to be "before" its `.foo` parent](http://jsfiddle.net/Us2LM/4/). It could be your mixed use of `em` units and `in` units is causing some issues. That would not be a good way to insure you get the positioning you want. I would keep your units in `em`.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-elements are displayed inline by default. Also, they are placed within the content area of an element.

To make it appear 'on top' of that element, set the display to block.

Lastly, pseudo-elements should be initialized using the content property.

```
.foo::before { 
 content: url(./bar.svg);
 display: block;
}
```